# c# - write a single row from a 2d array every second

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a C# console app. The "app" is a poor mans matrix (ie. 1 and 0 fall down the screen).

I've managed to make two 2d arrays, one for `int` and one for `string`. The `int` array is filled by RNG, and those numbers are then converted into the `string` array.

What I would like to achive, is to print each row from the `string` array every second (`ElapsedEventArgs`).

What I'm thinking (but isn't working) is something like this...

```
        static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_countDown-- <= 0)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Clear();
                aTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                PrintSingleLine();
            }
        }

        static void PrintSingleLine() // this should write a single line every second
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <=pnms.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach(string str in pnms)
                {
                    Console.Write(str);
                }
            }
        }

//if it helps, this is how you write the whole array

        static void PrintArray()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= pnms.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= pnms.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(nms[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I can provide any additional information, please let me know.

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**
So, since nothing was showing on the console, I decided to do it manually (one line per `Console.ReadLine();`. I figured out that i forgot to initalize the arrays (duh), and this is the code that prints the current line. It overwrites the previous one, but hey, it's something...

```
        public static int col = 0;
        static void PrintSingleLine()
        {
            for (int i = col; i <= pnms.GetLength(0) - 1;)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= pnms.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(pnms[col, j]);
                }
                break;
            }
            col =+ 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=netcore-3.1

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generating-random-number-and-string-in-C-Sharp/

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, had some time to spare. This is the result. Good luck!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace PoorMatrix
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer aTimer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;

            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

            // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Clear();

            // Start the timer
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateRandomChars(100).ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));

        }

        private static List<string> GenerateRandomChars(int paramCharAmount)
        {
            List<string> tempChars = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < paramCharAmount; i++)
            {
                int LetterNumberOrEmpty = RandomNumber(0, 100);

                switch (LetterNumberOrEmpty)
                {
                    case int n when n < 41:
                        tempChars.Add(RandomNumber(0, 1).ToString());
                        break;

                    case int n when n < 81:
                        tempChars.Add(RandomLetter(RandomBool()));
                        break;

                    case int n when n < 101:
                        tempChars.Add(" ");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return tempChars;
        }

        private static bool RandomBool()
        {
            return new Random().NextDouble() >= 0.5;
        }

        public static int RandomNumber(int paramMin, int paramMax)
        {
            return new Random().Next(paramMin, paramMax);
        }

        public static string RandomLetter(bool paramIsLowerCase = false)
        {
            // Unicode/ASCII Letters are divided into two blocks
            // (Letters 65–90 / 97–122):
            // The first group containing the uppercase letters and
            // the second group containing the lowercase.  

            // char is a single Unicode character  
            char offset = paramIsLowerCase ? 'a' : 'A';
            const int lettersOffset = 26; // A...Z or a..z: length=26  

            var @char = (char)new Random().Next(offset, offset + lettersOffset);

            return paramIsLowerCase ? @char.ToString().ToLower() : @char.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: I see you put the whole logic up there. I already have the "backgeound" logic there, I just don't know how to print the array one line at a time. Thanks for the effort though. +1 =)

Comment: An observable timer would also be a fun choice. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229503(v=vs.103)